# Submit input doesn't get posted in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, submit

The form gets submitted but not the submit button.
`var_dump($_POST)` shows all the variables submitted by the form but not `'submit1' => string 'Insert' (length=6)`.

Chrome posts the submit button, but Firefox and IE do not.

Javascript:

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var self = this;
  ...
  self.submit();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Insert" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
<button type="submit" name="submit1">Insert</button>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Insert" />
```

Comment: Until now i just added another hidden input, but this solution is better indeed. Thank you!